# How to find the first, second, third etc numbers of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've started learning about arrays and they've very confusing. I want to generate 4 numbers using this:

```
$numbers = range(1,4);
```

Then I shuffle with this:

```
shuffle($numbers);
```

Now I want to get each number as a variable, I've been told the best way is arrays. I have this code:

```
foreach($numbers as $number){

$test = array("first"=>"$number");
echo $test['first'];

}
```

What this does is echo all 4 numbers together, like "3142" or "3241" etc. Which is close to what I want, but I need all 4 numbers to have their own variable each. So I made this:

```
foreach($numbers as $number){

$test =     array("first"=>"$number","second"=>"$number","third"=>"$number","fourth"=>"$number");
echo $test['first']," ",$test['second']," ",$test['third']," ",$test['fourth'],"     <br>";

}
```

This just echoes the 4 numbers 4 times. I need "first" to be the first number, "second" to be the second number of the 4 and the same for the third and fourth. I've been searching the web but don't know specifically what to search for to find the answer.

If someone answers could they please put as much detail into what certain functions do as possible, I want to learn not just get working code :)

Comment: If you write the entire array `$test` out by hand, you don't even need a foreach loop. Simply write `array("first"=>$numbers[0], "second"=>$numbers[1] ... );`. Also, in the echo statement, replace the `,` with `.`, because you can't concatenate strings with `,`.

Comment: @treegarden Sorry I understand that last bit, I've always used commas :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1,4);
shuffle($numbers);
$test = array();

foreach($numbers as $k=>$v){
    $test[$k] = $v;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
?>
```

This will give you the output as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

After that you can do:

```
$myvar["first"] = $test[0];
$myvar["second"] = $test[1];
$myvar["third"] = $test[2];
$myvar["fourth"] = $test[3];
```

Every array has a key, value pair, if you have an array say:

```
$myarr = array("a", "b", "c");
```

then you can access the value "a" as `$myarr[0]`, "b" as `$myarr[1]` and so on.

In the for loop I am looping through the array with their key and value, this will not only give you the key of the array but also the value associated with that key.

[More on Array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm)

**Edit:**
Improving what [Luthando Loot answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178982/3145341):

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1,4);//generate four numbers
shuffle($numbers);//shuffle them

$test  =  array();//create array for the results
$words = array("first", "second", "third", "fourth"); //create your array keys
$i = 0;
foreach($numbers as $number){
   $test[$words[$i]] = $number;//add your array keys & values 
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test); //show your results
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [first] => 4
    [second] => 3
    [third] => 2
    [fourth] => 1
)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. Could you possibly explain them a bit more, I don't understand the $k=>$v bit and how the blank array links to become the numbers :S

Comment: Thanks Criesto, and that link is much better than the W3schools I've been using!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full code, try it

```
$numbers = range(1,4); //generate four numbers
shuffle($numbers);   //shuffle them

$test =  array(); //create array for the results
$words = array("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th","5th"); //create your array keys
$i=0;
foreach($numbers as $number){
   $test[] = array($words[$i]=>$number);  //add your array keys & values 
    $i++;
}
print_r($test); //show your results
```

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct you have an array and you want certain values from within it?

Then why not just use the [array keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php):

```
$array = array('peach','pear','apple','orange','banana');
echo $array[0]; // peach
echo $array[1]; // pear
echo $array[2]; // apple
```

Or you could [loop through the array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like so:

```
foreach ($array as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
  // First value in the array is now below
  echo $arrayKey; // 0
  echo $arrayValue; // peach
}
```

You can also check if a value is [in an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like so:

```
if (in_array('orange', $array)) {
  echo 'yes';
}
```

Edit:

```
// Our array values
$array = array('peach','pear','apple','orange','banana');
// We won't shuffle for the example, we need expected results
#$array = shuffle($array);
// We want the first 3 values of the array
$keysRequired = array(0,1,2);
// This will hold our results
$storageArray = array();
// So for the first iteration of the loop $arrayKey is going to be 0
foreach ($array as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
  // If the array key matches one of the values in the required array 
  if (in_array($arrayKey, $keysRequired)) {
    // Store it within the storage array so we know what value it is
    $storageArray[] = $arrayValue;
  }  
}
// Let's see what values have been stored
echo "<pre>";
print_r($storageArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Would give you the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'peach'
    [1] => 'pear'
    [2] => 'apple'
)
```

Comment: What I want is each of the numbers to have be their own variable :) Your answer looks like I put each number in the array manually, but the order of numbers changes each time (this is required) so that won't work?

Comment: @Ben You would simply need to loop through the array and store the first 3 values. Criesto has done this but i will give you another option to look at for further understanding.

Comment: Using the "arrayKey" and "arrayValue" tags are incredibly helpful, I understand it a lot more now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sizeof()` it is return size of array size, and pass the key value manually. Like-
`echo $numbers[0];
echo $numbers[1];
echo $numbers[2];`

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
$numbers[0];
$numbers[1];
$numbers[2];
$numbers[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make an array of keys as

```
$key = ['first','second','third','fourth'];
```

And then you can simply use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) as

```
$numbers = range(1,4);
shuffle($numbers);
$key = ['first','second','third','fourth'];
$result = array_combine($key,$numbers);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/421289)